# How can I manually annotate data in XML?

Tags: supervised-learning, annotation

I am involved in a project where we need a solution for manually annotating the contents of patient medical records stored in an XML format.
We need a tool to show the contents of the fields of the XML files, preferably adhering to the hierarchical structure of them. For each field, there should be a corresponding annotation or set of annotations. The annotation should at the very least be a text comment for a field in the record. If possible, it would be even better to be able to annotate selected words or groups of words in the text, possibly with relations between them.
The annotation tool should output the annotations in a format that retains the relations between the fields of the original XML files and their associated annotations.
Which tool can help do this, or does such a tool even exist?

Comment: XMLSpy? https://www.altova.com/xmlspy-xml-editor

Comment: I will try it out, thanks.